# Plotting a field inside of a shape

Tags: graphics, physics

[image]I want to plot a field of vectors revolving on the inside of a torus in the positive x-direction. I don't know how to constrain the field on Mathematica. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {Cos[u], Sin[u], u/10}}, {u,
   0, 20}]
  Line[x_] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[Table[.025, {50}]], Arrow@Line[x]]
RevolutionPlot3D[{2 + Cos[t], 2 + Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I want to plot vectors like these inside of my torus.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question and add the code you have tried and the problems you faced.

Comment: You need to add some picture to describe your demand.

Comment: What is the function about such field?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure of what vector field is desired.  It might be `{1, 0, 0}`, but I'll use `{-z, x, y}`:

```
VectorPlot3D[{-z, x, y},
 {x, -1.4, 1.4}, {y, -1.4, 1.4}, {z, -1.4, 1.4},
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Evaluate[(Norm[{x, y, z} - Normalize@{x, y, 0}] /. 
        Abs -> Identity // Simplify) < 1/3]], 
 VectorPoints -> Fine]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is what I needed, well not exactly of course but the framework! Thank you so much!

Comment: `SliceVectorPlot3D` also can help?

Comment: @yode I thought about it for showing the v.f. ***on*** the surface but only now thought about showing it inside the surface, if that's what you mean. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPr9n.png